# Git, github вопросы

Tags: git, github

Прошу помочь, возникло 2 вопроса:

1. git и github это разные вещи или одно и то же?
2. Зачем вводить email при настройке git и на что это влияет?
3. Например, я ввожу команду git add filename.html и куда сохраняется файл? В github или же локально, на мой компьютер? Если локально, то куда этот проект сохраняется?

Прошу не судить строго, только начинаю изучать git....

Comment: https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Github, если кротко, это сервер, на котором установлен git server + веб морда для него.

Вот что пишут на [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub):

> Веб-сервис основан на системе контроля версий `Git` и разработан на `Ruby on Rails` и `Erlang` компанией `GitHub, Inc` (ранее `Logical Awesome`). Сервис бесплатен для проектов с открытым исходным кодом и (с 2019 года) небольших частных проектов, предоставляя им все возможности (включая SSL), а для крупных корпоративных проектов предлагаются различные платные тарифные планы.

---

2. Email и имя идентифицируют пользователя в git.

   `$ git config --global user.name "Kamaz Othodov"`

   `$ git config --global user.email kamaz.othodov@gmail.com`

---

3. Когда вы делаете **git add** и **commit** - файл попадает в Ваш локальный гит репозиторий (папка **.git** внутри папки Вашего проекта), чтобы отправить его на **github** надо сделать **push**, но если не беспокоитесь за сохранность исходного кода, можно все хранить в локальном гите (или поднять свой сервер), мало того можно обмениваться кодом с другими разработчиками, не используя "центральный" git репозиторий.

Comment: Если я разрабатываю проект самостоятельно, могу ли я НЕ делать push, а хранить файлы только локально? И главный вопрос, который у меня возник: могут ли как нибудь мои файлы уйти на гитхаб, если я не делаю push (паранойя)?

Comment: @IllyaIllya Гит имеет точно такое же отношение к гитхабу, как компьютер к интернету. И в том и другом случае одним можно без проблем пользоваться без подключения к другому. Аккаунт на гитхабе для применения гита совсем необязателен, как и сам гитхаб.